# How can I set the layout_gravity of navigation drawer fragment in base of rtl or ltr language?

Tags: android, navigation, right-to-left, drawer

I am writting my application in rtl language. I have set my navigation drawer to come from right to left when the phone language is English. But when I change the phone's language to farsi (rtl language) it brings me the error that says: "No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT".
So how can I set my navigation drawer to come from right in both languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Gravity.START and Gravity.END instead of left/right.
If you specify your drawer as Gravity.START, it will show on the left for English and on the right for Farsi.

Comment: yesit become that way that you said but i want that in both languages it become from right to left @Francesc

Comment: If you want your drawer always on the right side regardless of language, then use Gravity.RIGHT.

Comment: thank Francesc. it worked for me. ofcourse i write some code to complete your idea. thats it: if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) { mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT); } else {mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);}